# SQL Server Configuration Manager is Empty not showing any connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 installed.

It doesn't show any connections in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

When I open the Configuration Manager, it shows this.

[image]

how to solve this to show the connections like TCP/IP etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to run `SQLServerManager12.msc` in order to open the configuration manager.
Solved.